# Why Chrome cannot open Plugins on Windows 10?

Tags: google-chrome

I'm using Windows 10 64-bit. I have the latest Chrome version installed (57.0.2987.110 at the time of writing this post).

When I type `chrome:plugins`in the address bar, I get an `ERR_INVALID_URL` error, meaning that Chrome cannot reach the requested site.

Why is this happening? What can I do to open Plugins in Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has removed this "hidden page" completely.

Extensions are still available and there is an internal Adobe PDF reader and Flash player, both now modifiable under Settings-->Privacy-->"Content settings..."